# Aliases fail to persist after sourcing script

Tags: bash, alias

Here is my script:

```
echo "Defining aliases"
echo $$
echo "
s=screen
v=vlock -a
j=jobs
" | sed '/^$/d' | while read alias
do
  echo $$
  alias "$alias"
  alias | wc -l
done
```

And here is its output:

```
parthian@computer$ . aliases 
Defining aliases
3744
3744
4
3744
5
3744
6
parthian@computer$ ps -p $$
PID TTY          TIME CMD
3744 pts/1    00:00:03 bash
parthian@computer$ alias | wc -l
3
```

I'm flummoxed. This is some of the most straightforward code I've ever written, and it's not doing what it's supposed to do.

**EDIT:** When I change the echo lines from `echo $$` to `echo $$ $BASHPID`, the second PID (`$BASHPID`) is different inside the loop, but `$$` remains the same throughout. Could this be the issue?

Comment: And it can't be that I'm not making enough blood sacrifices to Stallman's beard, because I sacrificed my last oxen just yesterday.

Comment: By putting the alias definitions on the RHS of a pipe (`... | while read ...`), you are implicitly confining their scope to a subshell, I think: see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don’t believe everything a computer tells you.

```
$ ps -p $$
PID TTY          TIME CMD
3744 pts/1    00:00:03 bash
$ ps -t pts/1
PID TTY          TIME CMD
3744 pts/1    00:00:03 bash
4285 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
$ echo foo | while read x
do
        ps -t pts/1
done
PID TTY          TIME CMD
3744 pts/1    00:00:03 bash
4287 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
4288 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

```
$ echo "$$, $BASHPID"
3744, 3744
$ echo foo | while read x
do
        echo "$$, $BASHPID"
        ps -t pts/1
done
3744, 4292
PID TTY          TIME CMD
3744 pts/1    00:00:03 bash
4292 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
4293 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

When you do `some_command | while …`,
the shell puts the `while` loop into a subshell,
but `$$` continues to report the PID of the main (parent) process. 
In bash, `$BASHPID` reveals the truth.

Consider doing

```
while read alias
do
  alias "$alias"
done << EOF
s=screen
v=vlock -a
j=jobs
EOF
```

Comment: Arrghhh.  I didn't see your edit until I had finished typing my answer.  Hope it helps anyway.

Comment: It does. Seems silly, but it hadn't occurred to me to use a heredoc- thanks!

Comment: It is also mentioned in `bash` man page:    "[$]$      Expands to the process ID of the shell.  In a () subshell, it expands to the process ID of the current shell, not the subshell." May be it also applies to subshells created for pipes